# What types of higher than undergarduate degrees look exceptionally good relative to other equal level degrees?

Tags: career-path

I've heard a few people get exceptional job offers (huge pay and great benefits) just by getting a masters in certain fields. This has happened more than once. They describe a wild job offer as though their grades and institution (inside the US) had little or no impact. Instead, it was more about the degree title alone. (If I recall correctly, one individual was not even interviewed. The employer saw they had a PhD in some field, and gave them an incredible offer.)

To be more specific, which masters or PhD level degree did you have observed graduates get exceptional (almost over the top) job offers? Also, why do you think that degree is viewed so highly?

Comment: Just be in the right place at the right time.

Comment: Can you ask those individuals?

Comment: I hope you aren't going to use such information to choose your life's direction. Right this instant, someone with a degree in virus related pharmacology gets a pretty nice ticket. Next year. Who can say?

Comment: Comments aren't for extended discussion. I'm asking for instances people have observed.

Comment: People have only their own experience..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those stories exist, but not all of them are true. Be careful and look at the source of the story: Does it come from the institution itself (who is trying to "sell" its program), or from someone who is trying to make her or himself look important by telling about the wonderful job offer(s) they received? Also consider if this is it a selection of success stories or if this somewhat representative of the experience of all the students who finished that course.

Moreover, even if a field of study is now lucrative, that does not mean that it will still be lucrative when new students finish their education. [Pork cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_cycle) are a big problem for many fields of study.

Comment: There are quite a lot of incredibly stupid (even evil) people with advanced degrees from, say, Ivy League places and other R1's.

Comment: @Buffy that is undoubtable true. However, I don't understand how that relates to my answer. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Actually more of a heads-up to the OP. Your answer is fine.